# Webstreaming ERROR from OpenCV when streaming with flask in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video-streaming, raspberry-pi4

I want to stream on the website using Raspberry Pi, Pi Camera, flask and OpenCV.

So I wrote the streaming code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)

def GenerateFrame():
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while True:
                ref, frame = capture.read()
                if not ref:
                        break
                else:
                        ref, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
                        frame = buffer.tobytes()
                        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                               b'Content-Type: image /jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
@app.route("/")

def Index():
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
        return Response(GenerateFrame(), mimetype = 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary = frame')


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = "8080")
```

and index.html

```
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset = "utf-8">
                <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                <link rel = "stylesheet" href="https:??stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                        integrity = "sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJw8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymou">

                <title>WEBCAM STREAMING</title>
        </head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class = "row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h3 class = "mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
                                <img src="{{url_for('video_feed')}}" width = "100%">
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the Python code.

The code well functioned but, I can't see the streaming video when I visit my IP address.

When I visit the website, the error code wrote like below in Raspberry Pi terminal.

```
@raspberrypi:~/opencv $ sudo python app_start.py
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
 * Serving Flask app "app_start" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
192.168.123.9 - - [16/Jan/2024 10:29:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[ WARN:1] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src1 reported: Device '/dev/video0' is busy
[ WARN:1] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:1] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:1] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
192.168.123.9 - - [16/Jan/2024 10:29:43] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I find the sentence " module v4l2src1 reported: Device '/dev/video0' is busy".

But I haven't used the `video0` except for running this code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: that's because you're trying to access the same camera from multiple connections

Comment: Use webcam instead of PiCamera2